# How to import "scikit-multilearn" python library in Azure Machine learning

Tags: python, azure, scikit-multilearn

1. We are trying to import "`scikit-multilearn`" library in python
   script and we are using this python script in Azure machine learning
   algorithm to achieve our goal.

   We have written our script in jupyter notebook and running our
   script in algorithm.

   while run the python script we are getting below error,

   > ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
   >   last)  in ()
   >   ----> 1 from skmultilearn.problem_transform import LabelPowerset
   >         2
   >
   > ImportError: No module named 'skmultilearn'

   Need help in getting solution on the same.

---

***Edited:***

We have followed the steps mention above and through it successfully. Refer below image for details.
[image]

But after adding the DataSet List, dragging it to the third node of
the Execute Python Script in Machine learning experiment, we ran it
and it throws the below error:

```
Error 0085: The following error
occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for
more information:

---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ---------- Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent
call last):   File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 189, in batch
    mod = import_module(moduleName)   File "C:\pyhome\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)   File "C:\temp\f99d826a21174a1a87b0dfd39e10fcb5.py", line 16, in <module>
    from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN ImportError: No module named skmultilearn.adapt Process returned with non-zero exit code 1

---------- End of error message from Python  interpreter  ---------- Start time: UTC 12/21/2017 07:26:59 End time: UTC 12/21/2017 07:27:13
```

Also, we have written just “from skmultilearn.adapt import
MLkNN” statement in the python script to check library import.

[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome here ! If you have added the part of your code that generated the problem in order to get a reproducible example you would get lot more help !

Comment: Hi I have used azure Machine Leaning Experiment with using Execute Python Script function to import scikit-Multilearn package for using Multi label class algorithm in azure ML Experiment but its was showing error.above pics you can see the details

Answer (score 1):

> ImportError: No module named 'skmultilearn'

It seems that you did not import `scikit-multilearn` package successfully.

I offer the below steps for you to show how to import `skmultilearn` package in `Execute Python Script`.

***Step 1*** : Use the `virtualenv` component to create an independent python runtime environment in your system.Please install it first with command `pip install virtualenv` if you don't have it.

[image]

If you installed it successfully ,you could see it in your python/Scripts file.

[image]

***Step2*** : Run the commad to create independent python runtime environment.

[image]

***Step 3*** : Then go into the created directory's Scripts folder and activate it (this step is important , don't miss it)

[image]

Please don't close this command window and use `pip install scikit-multilearn` to download external libraries in this command window.

[image]

***Step 4*** : Compress all of the files in the Lib/site-packages folder into a zip package (I'm calling it scikit-multilearn- package here)

[image]

***Step 5*** ：Upload the zip package into the Azure Machine Learning WorkSpace DataSet.

[image]

specific steps please refer to the [Technical Notes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/cdb56f95-7f4c-404d-bde7-5bb972e6f232/).

After success, you will see the uploaded package in the DataSet List

[image]

***Step 6*** ： After success, you will see the uploaded package in the DataSet List, dragging it to the **third node** of the Execute Python Script.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have not able to entered long comments, so posted my comments as answer. Thank you !

Comment: @user8579066 That's all right. I just modified your post's format so that it becomes more clear. Next time , you could update your further steps in your question.  So, let me check the error log you offered and try to figure it out.

Comment: @user8579066 You delete your further steps?

Comment: I am deleted previous steps. Its deleted by stack over flow team

Comment: @user8579066 Fine.Would you please update your previous steps in your question?

Comment: Edited my question with more descriptive as requested.